# Azure Web Jobs Calling it from C# with Parameters

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I am trying to call a webjob from asp.net c# page. When I check the log it shows that it run but nothing is in the log except. It should say "Dan's Phone Number is 5551212"

```
[01/15/2015 14:29:18 > 898371: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[01/15/2015 14:29:20 > 898371: SYS INFO] Run script 'EncodeAsset.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[01/15/2015 14:29:20 > 898371: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[01/15/2015 14:29:20 > 898371: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\triggered\EncodeAsset\EncodeAsset.exe";
        myProcess.Start();
    }
}

class Program
{
    // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    static void Main()
    {
    }

    public static void Testing([QueueTrigger("queuejobs")]string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dan's Phone Number is:", message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a continuous WebJob, the idea is to trigger the function based off an Azure storage queue or blob event, not to directly invoke the function from your client code.  Here, you have a `QueueTrigger` annotation, which is listening for new messages on the `queuejobs` queue. To invoke the WebJob function, you need to enqueue a string message on the same queue.  To do this, you would do something like the following in your `Button1_Click` handler
(From http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues):

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the queue client.
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a queue.
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("queuejobs");

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

// Create a message and add it to the queue. 
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("5551212");
queue.AddMessage(message);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job).

> To run with arguments use the arguments parameters that will be added to the script when invoked. It also gets passed to the WebJob as the WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS environment variable.
>
> POST /api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/run?arguments={arguments}

Your url would look like this ultimately.  Don't forget to pass credentials (username and password which you can find if you download your publish profile).

```
https://{site}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{jobname}/run?arguments={arguments}
```

Just depends what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample on MSDN which is pretty straightforward. Hope that will help you
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Azure-Website-with-b4391eeb

Comment: I looked at that sample and read his blog. I am not that familiar with MVC. I am assuming this is the line to call program.cs (the web job) thumbnailRequestQueue queueClient.GetQueueReference("thumbnailrequest"); How do I pass a parameter to program.cs?

Comment: Compile the Console Application and get the executable file path.
After that you simply need to do is in the ASP.NET code
 Process.Start("Path/To/Exe.exe", "your arguments");

Comment: I changed the code per your suggestion, same thing happens. The web jobs does not execute through the web page; however when I run the webjob through the Azure Portal it works fine. The path to the file is correct.

Comment: I also tried this  Process.Start(@"D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\triggered\EncodeAsset\EncodeAsset.exe");

Comment: I forgot to add, my website is "Always On". I don't know if that makes a difference